# What's the word for day/night?

Tags: synonyms, time, hypernyms

So I'm customizing  a WordPress (cms) for hotel for a client and he asked me to do add a new functionality that is a options dropdown where the user can select  "time" like

> Time:
>   - Day
>   - Night

I don't think time is the correct word.  What word is there to describe that "time" label?  What's the word for day/night?

Comment: You didn't complete your last sentence.

Comment: sorry, I've corrected it ! :)

Comment: So what you want is a word _superior_ to day and night? The only thing that comes to mind is "part of a day" as it divides the day based on daylight. But it also distinguishes morning, evening, ...

Comment: You may use **Time of day** that refers to either a precise time (e.g. 10:00) or parts of the day (e.g. morning or dawn).

Answer (score -3):

Tough one!  Here's my proposal:

**When**